# Unable to download SVG attachments from atlassian ticket

Tags: jira

I am using Atlassian Jira to generate issues on different tickets. Recently, I am facing a problem, the tickets which contains attachments of SVG file is not downloading.

I can preview the attachments. Upon right clicking on the preview, the menu displays "Save image as..." which saves the image in JPG format. However, the attachments are in SVG formats. There is a button with cloud icon on each attachments that potentially saves the attachment in original format. But this button is not working anymore. I am using Chrome 110 on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made few tests.
On my Jira instance I can download SVG in attachment list view and in preview popup.
Interestingly SVG does not work when added to description.

[image: Jira issue view with SVG attachment]

Also I have tested if SVG attachment can be downloaded by API.
I have used [External Share for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220441/external-share-for-jira?tab=overview) and created shared link: https://jira.external-share.com/issue/a859d6e8-5172-4448-ad64-148577439638
You can download SVG from there. Under hood it does fetch attachment via API.

Few random though:

- Try disable all browser plugins. Maybe one of them interferes.
- Jira does roll new updates incrementally. Maybe your instance is affected with update that has this problem
- I do not see anything related on [public bug tracker](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-30128?filter=98690&jql=project%20%3D%20JRACLOUD%20AND%20issuetype%20in%20(Bug%2C%20%22Support%20Request%22)%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22svg%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC). Maybe you should create ticket there?
- Try [contact Atlassian directly](https://support.atlassian.com/)

Comment: Thank you, it has resolved the issue.